# Recoverable fatal error: Object of class newclass could not be converted to string in C:\xampp\htdocs\learn\index.php on line 16

Tags: php

I just started programming in PHP, and now I'm stuck on this one error

> Recoverable fatal error: Object of class new class could not be
>   converted to string in C:\xampp\htdocs\learn\index.php on line 16

```
<?php
class newclass
{
    public $info = "hey there";
    public $err = "this is the class called ".__CLASS__."!";

    public function __construct()
    {

        echo "this class has been instantiated";
    }
    public function toString()
    {
        echo new render();
        return $this->err;
    }

    public function conn($name)
    {
        $this->info = $name;
    }
    public function getdata()
    {
        return $this->info;
    }
    public function __destruct()
    {
        echo "this is  the end of class";
    }
}
```

Comment: `echo new render();` this echo causing the problem I hope. You can try by commenting it out or use print_r instead of echo.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include a [mcve] which generates the error message you get.

Answer (score 2):

The method toString should be named __toString as that is the method that php will look for when trying to represent an object as a string.

Answer (score 0):

Please refer to the documentation regarding magic methods 

[PHP Magic Methods __toString](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.magic.php#object.tostring)

---

```php
public function toString() {}
```

becomes

```php
public function __toString() {}
```